# JS regex positive look behind * not greedy when it should?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, lookbehind

If I look at the docs, it says `*` should always be greedy yet in this case it is not:

```
// returns 'password*****' instead of 'password: *****'
'password: "something"'.replace(/(?<=password[ :]*)[^\n,]+/i, '*****')
```

Comment: Quantifiers aren't usually allowed by lookbehinds.

Comment: @Barmar in chrome it is compiling properly without any error, any reason for that ?

Comment: Sorry, apparently EcmaScript allows this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FROM TC39 DOCS [`lookbehind proposal`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind)

Patterns normally match starting from the leftmost sub-pattern and move on to the sub-pattern on the right if the left sub-pattern succeeds. When contained within a lookbehind assertion, the order of matching would be reversed. Patterns would match starting from the rightmost sub-pattern and advance to the left instead. For example, given `/(?<=\$\d+\.)\d+/`, the pattern would first find a number and ensure first that it is preceded by . going backward, then \d+ starting from ., and lastly $ starting from where \d+ within the assertion begins. The backtracking direction would also be reversed as a result of this.

---

Since your `[^\n,]+` will match all the characters except `new line and ,` so it will capture `:` also and your lookbehind will not see it as it is already captured by assertions after lookbehind,

what you can do is use `+` which will makes sure you match atleast `one space or :`

```js
'password: "something"'.replace(/(?<=password[ :]+)[^\n,]+/i, '*****')
```

Comment: +1 I was going to say this, but couldn't find a reference in time.  Since it looks like there's always a colon and space, it might be better to do something like `[ :]{2,}`

Comment: @Toto firefox doesn't support lookebhinds yet

Comment: So you can't use it in a production environment

Comment: @Toto no you can't unless you use some sort of libraries which has cross browser support of these features [`xregexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp)

Answer (score 1):

@CodeManiac's answer is correct; however, to improve your regex a little more, you might want to do something like this:

```js
const regex = /(password[: ]+)([^\n,]+)/i;
const passwordStr = 'password: something';

console.log(passwordStr.replace(regex, '$1***********'))
```

With this, basically you're creating 2 matching groups: the prompt (`password:`) and the value (`something`).  You then replace the string with the first group (`$1` = `password:`) followed by asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

When processing a lookbehind it first searches for the pattern after the lookbehind, in this case `[^\n,]+`. Then it tests whether the lookbehind matches the part of the string to the left of that location; if it does then the match succeeds, otherwise it repeats, looking for the next match for the main pattern. It doesn't start by searching for the lookbehind.

`[^\n,]+` matches every substring in your input. When it gets to the substring `<space>"something"`, the lookbehind matches, since `[ ;]*` matches an empty string. It doesn't keep trying further matches to make the lookbehind match a longer prefix.